# Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException

Tags: xdb, azure, paas

Hi I was installing Sitecore in Azure Web App. It has been installed without SOLR cores in SOLR server (in this case I have a separate SORL VM along with Web apps for Sitecore PaaS). Once I have created the cores in SOLR VM, I am getting an error in XDb search.

In the experience profile, it is showing "An error occurred" and in the log, I have found the below statement.

ExceptionMessage: "One or more errors occurred."
ExceptionType: "System.AggregateException"

[image]

I was following the below URL for 
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuild-the-xdb-index-in-solr.html

I have also tried the "Manually post a rebuild document" method, still the error is there in the system.

Can any one please highlught any points.

Full log:

```
{Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "One or more errors occurred.",…}
ExceptionMessage: "One or more errors occurred."
ExceptionType: "System.AggregateException"
InnerException: {Message: "An error has occurred.",…}
ExceptionMessage: "The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError"
ExceptionType: "Sitecore.XConnect.XdbSearchUnavailableException"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient.d__9`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Operations.SearchOperationInvoker.d__2.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchHelpers.d__6`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.SearchDefinition`1.d__23.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncSearchHitEnumerator`1.d__21.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.d__18`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.d__17`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.AsyncEntityQueryProvider.d__8`1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.XConnect.SearchExtensions.d__16`1.MoveNext()"
Message: "An error has occurred."
StackTrace: "   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
↵   at Sitecore.Cintel.ContactSearchProvider.d__7.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.Cintel.ContactSearchProvider.c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0>d.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at Sitecore.Cintel.ContactSearchProvider.Find(ContactSearchParameters parameters)
↵   at Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.ContactController.Search(ContactSearchParameters parameters)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.c__DisplayClass6_1.b__3(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
↵   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
```

Comment: Can you confirm if your xconnect license are correct or Remove unused SC certificates from your 'current user' certificate stores.

Comment: what do you mean by mismatch between Sitecore core and Solr core? names are the same as the config but i am getting the same error exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. There was a mismatch between xDb cores name and Sitecore core. And use Kudo console to run any command in Web app.

Comment: Can you me more specific what was the problem, what do you mean with xDB cores name and Sitecore?

Comment: The SOLR core name in Sitecore & SOLR portal was different in this case somehow. Changed the name and then run the XConnectSearchIndexer -requestrebuild from Web app Kudo portal to re initiate the rebuild indexing. ANd then done.